# Mysql connection from remote PC

Tags: mysql, connection

What options do I have to enable in the my.ini of I want to connect my database from a remote PC.

This is the my.ini file content

```
[client]
port=3306
[mysql]
default-character-set=latin1
[mysqld]
# The TCP/IP Port the MySQL Server will listen on
port=3306
#Path to installation directory. All paths are usually resolved relative to this.
basedir = "C:/MySQL/"
#Path to the database root
datadir = "Z:/MySQL/Data/"
character-set-server=latin1
default-storage-engine = MyISAM
sql-mode="STRICT_TRANS_TABLES,NO_AUTO_CREATE_USER,NO_ENGINE_SUBSTITUTION"
max_connections=100
query_cache_size=0
table_cache=256
tmp_table_size=33M
thread_cache_size=8
myisam_max_sort_file_size=100G
myisam_sort_buffer_size=66M
key_buffer_size=53M
read_buffer_size=64K
read_rnd_buffer_size=256K
sort_buffer_size=256K
innodb_buffer_pool_size=102M
innodb_thread_concurrency=8
innodb_additional_mem_pool_size=3M
innodb_flush_log_at_trx_commit=1
innodb_log_buffer_size=2M
skip-ssl
```

What else do I need in the my.ini. Do I have to restart the MYSQL server? 
I dont need a SSL connection because this is a local network.

Comment: Now it's running an upload process(Calculation and upload), so I can't restart the mysql server, but I will add the new user, I guess that was the problem. Thanks for your help.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Your my.ini looks fine. Do You have any actual problems with connecting to the mysql server? Can You connect to the server using mysql command line client? If not what message do You get? Two reasons why You can't connect I can think of:

- Port 3306 is blocked by firewall (on Your or server end)
- You try to connect using user/password that can connect only from local machine. Try to add user that can connect from any location (refer to [GRANT syntax](http://dev.mysql.com/doc/refman/5.0/en/grant.html), look for '%' wildcard)